# How to config Apache2 to redirect URL from www to without the www

Tags: redirect, apache2

Does this is a valid redict command to redict the users that write the www prefixe in the URL to the same URL without the www.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName example.org
        ServerAlias www.example.irg

        RedirectMatch 301 https://www.example.org https://example.org
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not valid, `RedirectMatch` cannot see your domain, the regex works only on your URL-path.

https:// `domain.com` `/my-URL-path`

You can use these rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

A query on `https://www.example.org/home` will be redirected to `https://example.org/home`